# How could I generate the whole octave with Web Audio API?

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I am learning about Web Audio API from [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/).

If I load a piano sound of the DO note with Web Audio API, how could I generate RE, MI, FA, SOL, LA, SI, DO2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing the "playbackRate" parameter of the AudioBufferSourceNode to adjust the speed (and therefore pitch).  Note, though, that sound samples like piano tend to sound distinctly unnatural when you return them more than a couple of steps - you typically will have multiple samples, not trying to cover more than half a dozen notes with a single sound sample.  (E.g. you'd sample DO, use it for RE and MI, sample FA... you get the idea.)

Comment: Thanks. This put me on my way. Is there some formula of defining the correct playbackRate for each note? It seems that I need to set values in float format.

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament#Calculating_absolute_frequencies.  In short, each half-step is 2 ^ (1/12) times the previous one; so if you have an audio buffer that represents C, to get C# you multiply the playbackrate of 1 by Math.pow(2,1/12).

Comment: But even if we load the sound , it doesn't sound natural. It seems very monotoneous , what else can we do there ?@cwilso

Comment: Record a lot more piano samples.  No, really - for a realistic sound, you do not want to have to stretch by more than a couple of semitones.  Most multisampled pianos sample every few notes.